# How I insert the name of a text file in a Column Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm reading data from a text file and I want to write a query to insert the name of the text file in a column called `FileName`.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE ##textFileData(rowData Nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @fiLeName varchar(max)
DECLARE @fiLePath varchar(max) = '\\PC\Folder\TextFile.TXT'

SET @fiLeName = 'BULK INSERT ##textFileData FROM ''' + @fiLePath + '''  
   with  (
   codepage = 65001
 )';


Exec (@fiLeName)
```

Expected Output:

```
TableName
----------
ID   FileName
1    File_Name.TXT
2    File_Name.TXT
3    File_Name.TXT
```

Is there a simple/fun way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us how do you read the data from this files/files ?

Comment: Of course there is a simple way. You update the rows your code inserted with the name of your source file after insertion. But you probably expect a solution where you don't have to write any additional code. So the short answer is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be something you are looking for:

If this is your full path:

```
DECLARE @fiLePath   VARCHAR(1000)
SET @fiLePath  = '\\Location\DISK\YOURFOLDER\File_Name.txt'
```

And this is your table:

```
create table TableName (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
                        , FileName varchar(500))
```

Then you can insert it like this:

```
insert into TableName
select RIGHT(@fiLePath, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@fiLePath)) -1)  file_name
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=387707f7d404b29874d8c953f24b662d)